# DC motor rpm change by under supplying voltage

Tags: voltage, brushless-dc-motor

If I have a 6V dc motor running at 20 RPM with a gearbox already attached and I only supply the motor with 5V from a cellphone charger what will my new rpm be?

Comment: likely zero....

Answer (score 2):

If the 5V supply holds up and the motor load (torque) is not too heavy, the speed should be somewhat less than ~5/6 of the speed at 6V. The value of 'somewhat' will increase (speed will decrease) increasingly non linearly with increasing torque until the motor stalls.

Unless the motor is very small, the charger may not like supplying the start-up surge for the motor and it may just sit there.